# Mysql Innodb deadlock problems on REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, deadlock

I want to update the statistic count in mysql.

The SQL is as follow:

```
REPLACE INTO `record_amount`(`source`,`owner`,`day_time`,`count`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE `record_amount` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
   `owner` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
   `source` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
   `day_time` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `src_time` (`owner`,`source`,`day_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

However, it caused a DEADLOCK exception in multi-processes running (i.e. Map-Reduce).

I've read some materials online and confused about those locks. I know innodb uses row-level lock. I can just use the table-lock to solve the business problem but it is a little extreme. I found some possible solutions:

1. change `REPLACE INTO` to transaction with `SELECT id FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE`
2. change `REPLACE INTO` to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

I have no idea that which is practical and better. Can someone explain it or offer some links for me to read and study? Thank you!

Comment: just use myisam for this table, it does not hold locks.

Comment: @Sebas Thank you. And I remember that myisam uses table-level lock, what if I just lock table in Innodb? Change sql schema is not the first choice as I have to convince the DBA.

Comment: I should have been more precise. It holds locks, but no transaction, therefore no deadlocks - which seems to be your problem. About the dba thing, you're right I guess. However log tables, count tables etc.. are typical implementation of myisam nested in an innodb database.

Comment: The other thing is: replace into sucks. It's not just 1 statement. It's DELETE + INSERT in 1. Terrible... You get a new id, and it's very intrusive. Inspect your `deadlock` and identify the object in fault. Based on this you can decide what to do. Otherwise, it's pure guess, and luck.

Comment: @Sebas thank you for your further explanation. I tried SELECT FOR UPDATE in transaction, only to generate too much connection to mysql. Now I try to figure out why row-level lock may cause deadlock in other operations in Innodb then so that I can persuade them into using myisam.

Comment: if you have access to these tables (I think you should, as they are located in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`), try investigating tables like `INNODB_LOCK_WAITS`, `INNODB_LOCKS`, `INNODB_TRX` during what you think is a deadlock. It will give you precious information.

Comment: finally we use the simplest way -- Myisam to solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Are you building a summary table, one source row at a time?  And effectively doing `UPDATE ... count = count+1`?  Throw away the code and start over.  MAP-REDUCE on that is like using a sledge hammer on a thumbtack.

```
INSERT INTO summary (source, owner, day_time, count)
    SELECT source, owner, day_time, COUNT(*)
        FROM raw
        GROUP BY source, owner, day_time
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + VALUES(count);
```

A *single* statement approximately like that will do all the work at virtually disk I/O speed.  No `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  No deadlocks.  No multiple threads.  Etc.

Further improvements:

- Get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT`; turn the `UNIQUE` into `PRIMARY KEY`.
- day_time -- is that a `DATETIME` truncated to an hour?  (Or something like that.)  Use `DATETIME`, you will have much more flexibility in querying.

To discuss further, please elaborate on the source data (`CREATE TABLE, number of rows, frequency of processing, etc) and other details.  If this is really a Data Warehouse application with a Summary table, I may have more suggestions.

If the data is coming from a file, do `LOAD DATA` to shovel it into a temp table `raw` so that the above `INSERT..SELECT` can work.  If it is of manageable size, make `raw` `Engine=MEMORY` to avoid any I/O for it.

If you have multiple feeds, [my high-speed-ingestion blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) discusses how to have multiple threads without any deadlocks.

Comment: map-reduce is for business, not just to update count. So actually my problem is how to deal with update count problem in MySQL innodb? how to avoid deadlocks or data-inconsistence in multi-processes environment? Now we just change the innodb to myisam to solve the problem.

Comment: And "Get rid of the AUTO_INCREMENT; turn the UNIQUE into PRIMARY KEY." seems a good solution~~ and I would like to know that how is the SQL you provided working in multi-processes environment? Thank you~

Comment: I always think in terms of multiple machines hitting the database 'simultaneously'.  So (unless I goofed), it should work fine (and probably faster) in a multi-process environment.  InnoDB's concurrency revolves around the `PRIMARY KEY`, regardless of whether it is `AUTO_INCREMENT` or a 'natural' PK.  Two `UNIQUE/PRIMARY` keys is slower and more deadlock-prone than having only one.